# MongoDB takes an hour to delete_many() 1GB of data

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

We have a 3GB collection in mongoDB 4.2 and this python 3.7, pymongo 3.12 function that deletes rows from the collection:

```
def delete_from_mongo_collection(table_name):
    # connect to mongo cluster
    cluster = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
    db = cluster["cbbap"]
    
    # remove rows and return
    query = { 'competitionId': { '$in': [30629, 30630] } }
    db[table_name].delete_many(query)
    return
```

Here is the relevant info on this collection, note that it has 360MB worth of indexes which are set to speed up retrievals of data from this collection by our Node API, although they may be the problem here.

[image]

The `delete_many()` is part of a pattern where we (a) remove stale data and (b) upload fresh data, each day. However, given that it is taking over an hour to remove the rows that match the query `{ 'competitionId': { '$in': [30629, 30630] } }`, we'd be better off just dropping and re-inserting the entire table. What's frustrating is that `competitionId` is an index, and as the first index in our compound indexes, I thought it should be very fast to drop rows using an index. I wonder if having 360MB of indexes is responsible for the slow deletes?

We cannot use the `hint` parameter as we have mongoDB 4.2, not 4.4, and we do not want to upgrade to 4.4 yet as we are worried about major breaking changes that may occur in our pipelines and our node API.

What else can be done here to improve the performance of `delete_many()`?

Comment: to troubleshoot if it is the indexes causing the issue, i am going to delete indexes before deleting many and see if performance improves

Comment: another note, we were running delete_many() in parallel on 12 collections at a time, perhaps this was cause of the slowdown. I will check if running on just 1 collection at a time improves performance

Comment: it seems like "doing too much at once" was the problem, as we are able to delete_many() in 3-5 minutes when running it on one collection at a time...

Comment: You can try/use the method `db.collection.remove` to delete documents - and this method allows generating a _query plan_ which can show the usage of index usage on the query filter.

Comment: What is your concern to upgrade MongoDB to recent version? All changes are properly documented.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am concerned that there may be breaking upgrades to our data ingestion pipelines and to our application. I would like to create a sandbox environment and test the upgrade before upgrading on production

Comment: You say, you have no test environment of your application???

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That is correct, we need to keep our mongodb and all other costs to a minimum for a bit longer

Comment: Which cost? You can install MongoDB on your local PC for free. For Development purpose even the Enterprise Edition. Basic MongoDB Atlas is also for free.